# Get paged category link programmatically

Tags: categories, links, api

I want to get the link to a category (specified by id) but with a paged value (e.g. page 3 of category id 4).

I was looking into [`get_category_link()`<sup>*Codex*</sup>](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link), but it only returns the link to the first page of the category.

Is there a build-in function that I can make use of to get the link to a category page that reflects the blogs URL-layout settings (`?paged=3`/ `/page/3`)?

**Edit:** I added [my solution as an answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26084/get-paged-category-link-programmatically/26149#26149).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean, categories aren't paged, archives are... are you referring to category archive paging and linking to specific pages in that category's archive?

Comment: I mean that `get_category_link` displays the first page only, as written in the question. This might be called category archive, right, so categories are paged (in archives). And that's what I mean :) - right now I'm adding stuff to the link based on what permalinks related getter functions of `$wp_query` return.

Comment: maybe [`add_query_arg`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg)?

Comment: `add_query_arg` might be helpful to streamline if permalinks are turned off, will check. I'll add my code so far.

Comment: `add_query_arg` would be the way to go imo.. you'd then not need the strpos line.

Comment: @t31os, @Bainternet: looked into `add_query_arg`, it's not clear to me what that function does, deals with lot of cases, all which do not apply for my URL - the "just" adding another parameter. It does not resolve with permalinks as far as I can see.

Comment: I guess i just don't follow exactly what it is you're looking for, an internal function that creates a category link using a pretty URL? If that's the case, then no i don't believe there's an internal function for that(could be wrong though).

Comment: @t31os: Thanks for the feedback. I'm looking for an API function that provides a link agnostic to how the blog is configured (any kind of link configuration that is available in core).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the code I have so far which looks like it does the job, I still wonder if there is a API function for the job:

```
/**
 * @param (int) $category_id
 * @param (int) $pagenum
 * @return string
 */
function get_category_paged_link($category_id, $pagenum)
{
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $link = get_category_link($category_id);

    if ($wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() || $wp_rewrite->using_index_permalinks())
    {
        $link = sprintf
        (
            '%s/%s/%d/',
            rtrim($link, '/'),
            $wp_rewrite->pagination_base,
            $pagenum
        );
    }
    else
    {
        if (false === strpos($link, '?'))
            $link .= '?';
        else
            $link .= '&';
        $link .= sprintf('paged=%d', $pagenum);
    }

    return $link;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found that `get_term_link()`(or similarly `get_category_link`) will output a pretty URL depending on where it's called, when called too early(i was testing inside the theme functions file initially) it will just output a regular query var style URL, eg. `http://example.com/?cat=5`, where as when called later on(i tested in the theme's footer), you'll get a permalink style URL, eg. `http://example.com/category/nicename`.

Clearly those functions rely on something that gets included later in the load sequence(at least after the theme's functions file), i can't pinpoint why they behave this way, but that's my initial observation, which also means my previous comment regarding there not being an internal function was incorrect.

Comment: So in short, depending on where and when you call the functions you may get a pretty url or a regular query string url.